# struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 16 in Python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code and  am trying to run it. But there is an error. Here is the code and the file that I am using.

```
import sys
import re
import subprocess as commands
import struct

class rbin:
    def file_op(self,rfile):
        self.readfile  = rfile
        self.wfile = open('loadmem.txt', 'w')
        for line in self.readfile.readlines():
                for cnt in range (0,4096,1):
                    x = cnt*16
                    test = line[x:x+16]
                    if (len(test) == 14):
                        magic = struct.unpack("<14b",test)
                        for i in range(0,14,1):
                                self.wfile.write("0x%X\n" % (magic[i]))
                    else:
                        magic = struct.unpack("<16b",test)
                        for i in range(0,16,1):
                            if ((x <= 498) | ((x <= 65520) & (x >= 65280))):
                                self.wfile.write("0x%X\n" % (magic[i]))

        self.readfile.close()
        self.wfile.close()

# Call Class
T = rbin()
# Call function from class
T.file_op(open('1.ex5','rb'))
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 30, in <module>
    T.file_op(open('1.ex5','rb'))
  File "check.py", line 19, in file_op
    magic = struct.unpack("<3b",test)
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 3
```

The file is: [1.ex5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JtBBw7gpGtRr05vy6ABAH8853AvFS-eJ/view?usp=sharing)

Please let me know how to eliminate the error and what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to readlines() will yield you the data from your current position in the file to the next \n (0x0a) character. Now since this is really a binary file, there really is no notion of a "linefeed".

If you open your file in a hex editor, you will see things like:

```
00000d70: 4451 baf1 dab3 7f69 ba67 a75b 1dee e6c2  DQ.....i.g.[....
00000d80: c816 a6cf be27 ace2 e6bb efef 0578 9a50  .....'.......x.P
00000d90: 0a86 28b8 1cae e9b4 e5ff ac5c e664 170a  ..(........\.d..
          ^                                    ^
          fake linefeed                        another fake linefeed
```

In that particular section of the file, there are less than 16 bytes, which is why your attempt to `struct.unpack` 16 bytes fails.

Moral: do not run readlines() on binary files. It will "work" (i.e. not throw an exception), but the data is not really lines of text.

Comment: So what is the solution? I can understand what you are saying. But I am in need of reading the files. I want to uncompress the files. That is the reason I need to nkow what I can do.

Comment: When parsing a binary file, use read(), not readline(). read() takes the number of bytes to read as an argument. So what do you use? Well, when parsing a binary file, you are aware of its format. E.g. if you know that the file starts with a 4-byte signature, then an 8-byte timestamp, then a 2-byte flag, then you first do read(4) and look for the signature, then do a read(8) and extract the timestamp, and then do read(2) to extract the flag. Keep walking down the file in this fashion.

Comment: That is the matter. I do not know what is in this binary. Thats why I am trying to walk blind. Can you help? I have shared iit with the question. You can check it as well.

Comment: You don't know what that file contains? You mean it could be a picture, a video, an audio clip, a library, an executable, a document, a firmware, anything? Sorry, that makes no sense at all. In any case, then, struct.unpack is not your problem. Maybe you should start another question with "How do I a parse a binary file whose format I do not know?"

Comment: I mean I know that the file is executable module for another executable. Now I want to read it out of the executable and not with the executable. I want to read this module.